# move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory

Tags: php, file-upload

So I want to be able to move the uploaded attachments to the specified directory depending on the month inside the year.

**I'm getting the following two errors**:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory
>   Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/private/var/tmp/phptmfv0g' to 'uploads/2020/01'

**Code**:

```
$dir = "uploads/" . date('Y') . '/' . date('m');

if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rtk']['tmp_name']['5']['file'], $dir);
```

So it creates the directory to build the folders, but I can't seem to move my contact form files into that directory at all - What could I be doing different?

[image]

**This used to work by placing all the attachments in the same directory**:

```
$file = "uploads/" . basename($this->get_last_name() . " - " . $this->get_first_name() . " - " . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"));

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rtk']['tmp_name']['5']['file'], $file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as the error says, the path you are trying to copy to is a directory not a file path

The problem is not about the month

It's that the path ends up as: `uploads/2020/01`

While it should be: `uploads/2020/01/filename.ext`

You can get original file name with `$_FILES['file']['name']` --> `$_FILES['rtk']['name']['5']['file']`

```
$dir = "uploads/" . date('Y') . '/' . date('m');
$fileName = $_FILES['rtk']['name']['5']['file'];
$fullPath = $dir . '/' . $fileName;

if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rtk']['tmp_name']['5']['file'], $fullPath);
```

--- To prevent users from replacing each other files you can add a unique prefix, for example just using `uniqid()`

```
$dir = "uploads/" . date('Y') . '/' . date('m');
$fileName = uniqid() . '_' . $_FILES['rtk']['name']['5']['file'];
$fullPath = $dir . '/' . $fileName;

if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rtk']['tmp_name']['5']['file'], $fullPath);
```

Comment: This is amazing help @SirNarsh, one thing tho - It looks like the file gets created as a directory because of `mkdir($dir, 0755, true);` - How would I tackle this?

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents yep, that was the problem, just split fullPath into file name and directory, so the mkdir gets the `$dir` only while the `move_uploaded_file` gets the whole path `$fullPath`...

Comment: Works like a charm - Thanks @SirNarsh

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the directory and filename for the destination:

```
$dir  = "uploads/" . date('Y') . '/' . date('m');
$file = basename($_FILES['rtk']['name']['5']['file']);

if (!file_exists($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['rtk']['tmp_name']['5']['file'], "$dir/$file");
```

Or if they exist, use the object methods as you did previously to build a filename:

```
$file = $this->get_last_name() . "-" . $this->get_first_name() . "-" . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
```